# C# remove special html tags by specific attribute value

Tags: c#, html

In the below html tags, I want to use c# programs to remove the whole tags which has the attribute values `"display:none"` in `style`:

```html
<td>
    <span style="display:none">
        <font color="#ffffff">OK</font>
    </span>
    <span>
    <font color="#ffffff">OK</font>
    </span>
</td>
```

and the html will become:

```html
<td>
    <span>
        <font color="#ffffff">OK</font>
    </span>
</td>
```

Besides using `Replace()` function, Can anyone suggest me some ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately you can use jQuery like sintaxys in C# using [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/csquery)

```
string htmlString = @"<td>
<span style=\"display:none\">
<font color=\"#ffffff\">OK</font>
</span>
<span>
<font color=\"#ffffff\">OK</font>
</span>
</td>";
var dom = CQ.Create(htmlString);
dom.Select("[style=display:none]").Remove();
```

I don't test it but is a good starting point

In a DOM with more than one display:none, as metioned @jamietre in comments

```
var dom = CQ.Create(htmlString);
dom.Select("[style]").Where(item=>item.Style["display"]=="none")).Rem‌​ove();
```

Comment: This would work if that was the only style; in order to test for situations where there could be more than one style, you could use linq: `CQ.Create(dom.Select("[style]").Where(item=>item.Style["display"]=="none")).Remove()`. This finds all elements having a style attribute; then iterates over them and returns a sequence of those with the "display:none" style, then wraps that sequence as a new CQ object, then removes it.

Comment: Is the best approach for this. Do you give me your permission to add it to my response? Or edit yourself! Or add a response with it, because I think is the best choice to @K.C

Comment: Sure go ahead and edit it! I didn't want to step on your toes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTMLAGILITY Pack to parse your html nodes safely

http://nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack